# ggplotly "what" error on help file examples

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I am trying to make some interactive plots to help me explore my data. However when I try and turn a ggplot into a plotly I get the following error

> Error in inherits(theme[[element]], ggplot_global$element_tree[[element]]$class) : 
>     'what' must be a character vector

This error message appears even when running example code, for example the first example on the ggplotly help shown below.

```
ggiris <- qplot(Petal.Width, Sepal.Length, data = iris, color = Species)
ggplotly(ggiris)
```

However if I use plotly directly then the no error message appears. The below works without issue.

```
allCities <- txhousing %>%
  group_by(city) %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~date, y = ~median) %>%
  add_lines(alpha = 0.2, name = "Texan Cities", hoverinfo = "none")

allCities %>%
  filter(city == "Houston") %>%
  add_lines(name = "Houston")
```

I am using ggplotly 4.8.0 My session info is as follows.

> R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
>   Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
>   Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same error, when I restarted my R session and uploaded  `package::plotly` only, it worked fine. I think the issue was due to a conflict with another package. It might have been `package::ggtern` for my case, i got this from the link below.

[Why does ggplotly break when ggtern is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56083771/why-does-ggplotly-break-when-ggtern-is-loaded)

I hope this helps.