# Why does ggplotly break when ggtern is loaded?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly, ggtern

I was hoping to use `plotly::ggplotly()` to plot a graph produced with `ggtern()` with a tooltip feature. But loading the package ggtern caused ggplotly to throw the following error:

> Error in inherits(theme[[element]], ggplot_global$element_tree[[element]]$class) : 
>     'what' must be a character vector

What's more, this error appears for all graphs, not just those produced by ggtern.

Here is an example.

```
library(ggplot2)

# This works
gg.mtcars <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) +
  geom_point()
plotly::ggplotly(gg.mtcars)

library(ggtern)

data("Feldspar")

gg.feldspar <- ggtern(data = Feldspar, aes(x = Ab, y = An, z = Or)) +
  geom_point()

# This throws an error
plotly::ggplotly(gg.feldspar)

# And now this throws an error too
plotly::ggplotly(gg.mtcars)
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I can fix your problem, but ggtern is known to extend ggplot in ways ggplot hasn't been designed for. To get around that, they had to re-implement a lot of things, including a lot of theme elements (see discussion here: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2540). The good news is that the issue is still open and somebody has stated intent to overhaul the way ggplot handles themes.

Comment: Thanks for that info. I fear this is more complicated than I imagined.